# working on angular where if and else condition. if condition has been worked correctly not else condition not working

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I have created the webpage where if the change=true then show "change is true". in change=false then show "change is false"

```
<div>
   <button (click)="onClick()">click</button>
   <p *ngIf="change;  else elseBlock">  change is true </p>

<ng-template>
    <p #elseBlock>change is flase</p>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-if',
  templateUrl: './ng-if.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ng-if.component.css']
})
export class NgIfComponent implements OnInit {

  change: boolean;

  constructor() {

    this.change=false;
  }

  onClick(){
    this.change=!this.change;
  }


    ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The else block should have its own condition:

```
<div>
   <button (click)="onClick()">click</button>
   <p *ngIf="change">  change is true </p>

<ng-template>
    <p *ngIf="!change">change is flase</p>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template  #elseBlock>
    <p> change is flase</p>
</ng-template>
```

is the correct statement. write template reference  name in the  `<ng-template>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Use tag `#elseBlock`on ng-template

```
<div>
 <button (click)="onClick()">click</button>
 <p *ngIf="change;  else elseBlock">  change is true </p>

 <ng-template #elseBlock>
   <p>change is flase</p>
 </ng-template>
</div>
```